# Android- Volver del segundo plano a primer plano

Tags: java, android, android-studio

mi consulta es sobre mi app android y manejos de estados.
tengo las siguientes activitys
login>Main
Cuando me logueo dejo en las SharedPreferences un estado de logueado, y quiero que cuando la deje en pause() a la app y vuelva a ingresar en login verifique el estado en las SharedPreferences, y de ser true , que ingrese a Main.
Ahora genera siempre un segundo Main, que aparece cuando hago Logout, siempre para salir lo tengo q hacer dos veces

```
    if (sesionManager.GetLogin()){
        Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        this.finish();
    }
```

sesionManager.GetLogin() me devuelve el estado en las SharedPreferences.
Muchas gracias

Comment: Buenas, a que te refieres cuando dices "quiero que la deje en pause()" significa que destruyes la app? o lo mandas a background?

Comment: cuando la mando a background